# Find next node from source on the path to given node in a graph

Tags: graph-theory, shortest-path, undirected-graph

Given an undirected graph, it's quarantined that there is exactly one path from each two vertices and all the nodes are connected. I need to write an efficient algorithm to answer the queries. In a query you're given two nodes: "from", "to" (nodes are integers), find node connected to "from" that's on the shortest path to "to").

Using bfs for each query isn't good enough (constrains are: 2*10^5 nodes and 2*10^5 queries).

Comment: "there is exactly one path from each two vertices" but "the shortest path"  If there is exactly one path, then it is meaningless to ask for the shortest of one path!!  You need to google Dijkstra algorithm.